# Please i need help about BitlyCore.com

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoind, bitcoin-core-development

Please I need help. I want to know if anyone knows about BitlyCore.com I have been running the full block for days now and it's just stuck at 87% please I need help.

Comment: I have never heard of Bitly Core. The site looks new, I can't find source code. Unless there is evidence to the contrary, I would operate under the assumption that it's a scam to steal your bitcoins.

Comment: I see. Maybe you can give me your telegram so I can show you my wallet I believe you can understand. I have 18 word phrase and password.

Comment: Firstly, I would recommend that you keep all your communication for getting help on Bitcoin in the public, and you should certainly never share your 18 word phrase and password with anyone. Secondly, why are you bent on using BitlyCore? Did you already receive a payment?

Comment: Yes I did and I have a wallet but I’ve been trying to download the full blockchain so I could access my account but it’s stuck at 87%. So I don’t know how to go about with this. I need help if anyone helps me I will reward them.

Comment: Again, browse the bitlycore page a bit. All the links to code, for developers etc. lead to placeholder pages or nothing. It's almost definitely a scam or malware. Did you create the wallet yourself or was it given to you? If you created it yourself, why do you think you need to use bitlycore?

Answer (score 1):

Tons of red flags here.

1. I've been around for a while and have never heard of this client.
2. Browsing the site, all the pages dedicated to code or developer documentation are non-existent or lead to placeholders.
3. I reached out to Will Binns whose name is given as the maintainer of
   the ostensible "Bitcoin client" Bitly Core on the "developer
   documentation page" (which looks like it was scraped from
   bitcoin.org). Will Binns tells me that he is unaffiliated with the
   project.

The obvious explanation is that the software is either **malware or part of a scam**. I would recommend that you do not install it, do not let it interact with any wallet backups, and regard anyone who recommended its use with suspicion.