# Bitly core website not loading

Tags: bitcoin-core

I misplaced my previous laptop, and I got a new one, I downloaded my wallet from Bitly core using my 18 word passphrase, I have been loading the nodes and it got stuck on 87%, I tried visiting the website, and it looks like it has been deleted, I've got about 5BTC there, please help me..

Comment: Sorry to break that to you, but I looked at that site a few days ago when another person asked about Bitly Core. All the links to developer resources and source code were either lifted from Bitcoin.org or just placeholders. I'm pretty sure that it was a scam and not a legit wallet.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Bitswallet core](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/103088/bitswallet-core) or [Please, I need help about Bitlycore.com](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/105690/13866)