# Help about BitlyCore

Tags: bitcoin-core, wallet

Please I need help. I want to know if anyone knows about BitlyCore.com I have been running the full block for days now and it's just stuck at 87% please I need help.

Answer (score 3):

It's a scam, it will never reach 100%. Your money is gone. You can report the theft to your local police but they won't be able to recover your money for you.

A safe website to find guidance on Bitcoin wallet software is https://bitcoin.org/en/choose-your-wallet

The correct website for downloading Bitcoin core is https://bitcoincore.org/en/download/

Ignore any other websites offering a wallet whose name ends with the word "core". There are many scammers who exploit the lack of knowledge of people new to Bitcoin.

---

See also

- [Bitly core website not loading](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/105901/13866)
- [Please i need help about BitlyCore.com](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/105690/13866)
- [Bitswallet core](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/103088/13866)

It will help to also read

- [Can't spend Watch-Only coins, have I been scammed?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/95596/13866)
- [How can I get a private key for this address](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/74362/13866)

Comment: but i can see there about 3 btc aviable. what cab i do now with the wallet?

Comment: The 3BTC is an illusion designed to trick you into paying fees and putting money in to achieve a minimum withdrawal threshold. All fake.

Comment: if i have tthe passphrase and password. can i use the 3 btc in other wallet?

Comment: (1) The people who tricked you, will have made sure you cant spend any money. Thieves usually don't leave $170,000 lying around where other people can take it. (2) a passphrase is not a seed-phrase. (3) Bitcoin-core doesn't use seed-phrases.