# Question about Multibit Core wallet - not sync

Tags: wallet, wallet-recovery, multibit

I hope you are alright.
I asked you for help.
I had the Multibit Core software wallet installed on my system and after a few years I now wanted to run and transfer my bitcoin balance.
From the time the software is opened, the software starts to sync, but my sync time is very long and it is almost 7 days now, my system is on and it has not been synced yet and it remains at 87% and practically does not move.
What can I do to sync faster and fix this problem?
If you have experience with this, please help.
Thank you.
I will attach an image of the software environment.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I'm afraid that this looks like another instance of the "BitlyCore malware" that was previously making the rounds, see e.g. [Help about BitlyCore](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/105940/5406).

The client's name appears to be a mash-up of Bitcoin Core, the reference implementation of Bitcoin, and MultiBit, a wallet software popular between 2011~2014 that was sunset in 2017.

I hope you didn't receive any funds to addresses generated with "Multibit Core". You should treat this piece of software with caution and probably get rid of it as thoroughly as you can.