# My multibit core synchronization is stuck Whats the reason

Tags: blockchain, wallet, address, private-key, synchronization

For the past six days since I downloaded the multibit core, I wanted to recover my wallet I still have my recovery phrase and password, and open the multibit core and the wallet was synchronization very slow and got up to 86% and was stuck for days now it’s still hasn’t added any percentage
Please what’s the caddie of this issue and how can I resolve it, it’s now six days since I started synchronization

Comment: *"What's the reason?"* -- the reason for this is downloading fake software designed by thieves to steal your money. I would only select software listed by a reputable source such as bitcoin.org "choose your wallet"

Answer (score 0):

Please regard this post: [Question about Multibit Core wallet - not sync](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/110389/question-about-multibit-core-wallet-not-sync)
for advice on how to deal with your malware.
Specifically:

> I hope you didn't receive any funds to addresses generated with "Multibit Core". You should treat this piece of software with caution and probably get rid of it as thoroughly as you can. -Murch